# compile error in hidden module Word 2010

Tags: vba, callback, ms-word

I have compiled a macro to format a generated report.
I have added this to a custom tab on the  Word ribbon. Whenever i try to run the macro by pressing the button on the custom tab i get the following error.

Compile error in hidden module: CallBackForRibbon

CallBackForRibbon is the name of the module i have the callback for the custom ribbon in. 
Module contains the code below:

```
'Callback for FORMAT onAction
Sub Format(control As IRibbonControl)
    Prog_Format
End Sub
```

Prog_Format is the name of the sub which contains the formatting macro.

I have tested the button on the ribbon with a simple message box and this works correctly so no issues with the call back but when i try to run the sub with the formatting macro i get the error.

The macro also runs fine in the VBA editor.

Can anyone point me to where i am going wrong?

Comment: Is that ***all*** of the code in that module?

Comment: Have you tried putting a break-point in Prog_Format then stepping through it when it's called from the Ribbon? Errors in code called by the procedure linked to the UI are often attributed to that procedure, rather than the one in which they actually occur...

Answer (score 0):

You can check where the compile error is by actually compiling your module before saving:

- Open the module in the VBA editor
- From the menu, choose *Debug* -> *Compile Project*

The IDE should now highlight the first line with a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

The error was occurring because the Module containing the Sub Prog_Format was also called Prog_Format. I was not aware that these could not be the same name. Becasue of this the contents of the Module was not visible to the  Sub Format.

Thanks for everyones help.